# If the previous and next rows are the same, add the full previous column

Tags: r

I have a data.table, I want to use Id as a different group, and the difference between the seconds between the previous line and the next line is more than 300.

Automatically add a new column, as well as the contents of the previous column, and can judge the need to add a few columns based on the difference in the number of seconds between the two columns

```
DT <-data.table(Id = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
                valueA = c(479117,479119,479117,479118,479118,479118,479118,479118,479121),
                valueB = c(209946,209948,209946,209953,209953,209953,209953,209951,209944),
                second = c(0,745,12,5,50,938,114,339,705))
```

Test dataframe

```
     Id   valueA   valueB   second
 1   A    479117   209946     0
 2   A    478419   209948   745 
 3   A    479117   209946    12
 4   A    479118   209953     5
 5   A    479118   209953    50
 6   B    479118   209953   938
 7   B    479118   209953   114
 8   B    479118   209951   339
 9   B    479121   209944   705
```

I would like the transformed dataframe to look like this

```
     Id   valueA   valueB   second
 1   A    479117   209946     0  #(original row 1)
#2   A    479117   209946   300  #(new row 2)
#3   A    479117   209946   300  #(new row 3)
 4   A    478419   209948   745  #(original row 2)
 5   A    479117   209946    12  #(original row 3)
 6   A    479118   209953     5
 7   A    479118   209953    50  #(original row 5)
 Because original row 5 and original row 6 Id is not the same, so don't compare
 8   B    479118   209953   938  #(original row 6)
 9   B    479118   209953   114
 10  B    479118   209951   339  #(original row 8)
#11  B    479118   209951   300  #(new row 11)
 12  B    479121   209944   705  #(original row 9)
```

Because the number of seconds between original row 1 and original row 2 is 745, the new row 2 and new row 3 will copy the contents of previous row. Why do you want to copy twice because 745/300=2.48(Round), take twice

The number of seconds between original row 8 and original row 9 is 366, so the new row 11 will copy the contents of previous row(8). Why do you want to copy it once, because 366/300=1.22, take it once(Round)

My original data has two million columns

The description is very complicated. I don't know if there is any way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody has come up with a smart solution I will give you a somewhat unelegant but probably working approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

grow_df <- function(x) {
  seconds <- DT %>% 
    filter(Id == x) %>% 
    pull(second)

  seconds2 <- c()
  for (i in seq(along = seconds)) {
    if (i == 1 || (i > 1 & seconds[i] - seconds[i - 1] <= 300)) {
      seconds2 <- c(seconds2, seconds[i])
    } else {
      for(j in 1:floor((seconds[i] - seconds[i - 1]) / 300)) {
        seconds2 <- c(seconds2, 300)
      }
      seconds2 <- c(seconds2, seconds[i])
    }
  }
  return(tibble(Id = x, second = seconds2))
}

map(DT$Id %>% unique, grow_df) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  left_join(DT, by = c("Id", "second")) %>% 
  fill(valueA, valueB) %>% 
  select(Id, valueA, valueB, second)
```

Note: For performance reasons you should not "grow" a vector like I did with `seconds2`. But its effective for the example.

Comment: Thanks, it works, I will try to understand the content, it shows insufficient memory for my huge data.

Comment: Iam glad if I could help you. Please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).